# How to get dragging coordinates for Chrome's Picture in picture Element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, picture-in-picture

I was able to use Picture in picture API But I am just wondering can we attached event handlers such as drag or resize in chrome browser desktop. I've tried to treat Picture in picture tab as normal DOM element and attach event handlers but it not working

My try

```
 listenForResize = e =>{
        console.log(e,'It is not working')
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        let cam = this.refs.pipCam;

        cam.addEventListener('drag', this.listenForResize )

    }
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/picture-in-picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PictureInPictureWindow](https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/#pictureinpicturewindow) that gets passed to the resolved Promise returned by [HTMLVideoElement.requestPictureInPicture](https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/#dom-htmlvideoelement-requestpictureinpicture) does expose `width` and `height` properties and an [`onresize`](https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/#eventdef-pictureinpicturewindow-resize) handler. However, nothing regarding the position in screen:

```js
pip_btn.onclick = (evt) =>
  video.requestPictureInPicture()
    .then((pip_window) => {
      console.log(pip_window);
      pip_window.onresize = (evt) => {
        console.log(pip_window.width, pip_window.height);
      };
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

```html
<video id="video" controls="" muted loop autoplay src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm"></video>
<button id="pip_btn">Enter PiP</button>
```